# .net file upload pre populate

Tags: .net, file-upload

Using the asp .net file upload control, is there a way to populate it with a file on page load?

When adding a new file it needs to be mandatory, but if editing the file details it should retain the original file or allow you to choose a new one

Answer (score 0):

No, because a file upload uploads a local file. You can't fix a path from the server, as a) you don't know whether the file will exist on the client and b) it's unsafe as it would allow for uploading arbitrary files from the client.

You'll just want to do something like this:

```
if FilesAreUploaded
{
    editFiles(uploadedFiles)
}
```